# Не правильно определяет корректность даты

Tags: c++, алгоритм, visual-c++, дата, календарь

Даны три натуральных числа, которые обозначают число, месяц и
год соответственно. Проверить корректность этой даты (например, 30 февраля 1900 года – некорректная дата). Найти номер этого дня с начала года.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <locale.h> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int p;
M: system("cls");
    setlocale(0, "");
    cout << "1) Условие задачи \n";
    cout << "2) Решение задачи \n";
    cout << "3) Выход из программы \n";
    cout << "\nВведите номер пунта меню: ";
    cin >> p;
    switch (p)
    {
    case 1: cout << "Даны три натуральных числа, которые обозначают число, месяц и год соответственно. Проверить корректность этой даты (например, 30 февраля 1900 года – некорректная дата). Найти номер этого дня с начала года. n"; //вывод условия на экран
        system("pause"); break;
    case 2:
        int date, m, year;
        char s;
        cout << "Введите дату:";
        cin >> date >> s >> m >> s >> year;
        bool a;
        a = true;
        switch (m)
        {
        case 1: a = (1 <= date <= 31 && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 2: a = (((year % 4 == 0 || (year%100==0 && year%400==0)) && 1 <= date <= 29 && 1 <= year <= 2022) || ((year % 4 != 0 || year%400!=0) && 1 <= date <= 29 && 1 <= year <= 2022)); break;
        case 3: a = ((1 <= date <= 30) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 4: a = ((1 <= date <= 31) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 5: a = ((1 <= date <= 30) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 6: a = ((1 <= date <= 31) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 7: a = ((1 <= date <= 31) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 8: a = ((1 <= date <= 30) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 10: a = ((1 <= date <= 31) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 11: a = ((1 <= date <= 30) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        case 12: a = ((1 <= date <= 31) && 1 <= year <= 2022); break;
        }
        if (a == true)
            cout << "Дата корректна\n";
        else
            cout << "Дата некорректна\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
        
    case 3: return 0;
    default: cout << "Введите номер пунта меню: ";
    }
    goto M;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Как минимум неверная проверка

```
(((year % 4 == 0 || (year%100==0 && year%400==0))
```

Високосный - если делится на 4, но не делится на 100. А если делится на 100 — то високосный только если делится и на 400. Ваш же код для любых делящихся на 4 дает високосность...

Зачем вы проверяете для каждого месяца год до 2022, не понимаю. Если уж считать, что 2023 — некорректная дата (почему?!), то выполнять проверку можно один раз.

И еще - учтите, что был переход с юлианского календаря (вот там високосный — просто если делится на 4) на григорианский, с "выпадением" некоторых дат вообще (каких именно — зависит от страны). Конечно, не думаю, что от вас это потребуют, но...

P.S. Я бы вообще переводил дату в [юлианский день](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1339450/195342), потом назад в григорианскую дату и смотрел, совпадают ли. А заодно и день с начала года получал простым вычитанием...

Answer (score 2):

Про саму проверку Harry написал точно и подробно - добавить нечего.
Есть ещё ошибки:

- напутали с продолжительностью месяцев - начиная с марта у вас идет неправильное количество дней
- не проверяете месяц на корректность - год проверяете, число проверяете, а месяц не проверяете
- пропущен 9 месяц (спасибо rotabor)

И несколько замечаний по коду.
Использование `goto` - плохая практика. Это прекрасно заменяется циклом

```
while(true)
{
    cout << "1) Условие задачи \n";
    cout << "2) Решение задачи \n";
    cout << "3 или другая цифра - Выход из программы \n";
    cout << "\nВведите номер пункта меню: ";
    cin >> p;
    if( p == 1)
       cout << "Даны три натуральных числа, ...";
    else if( p!=2 )
       break;
    ... // решение задачи

}
```

чтобы не копировать один и тот же код в операторе `switch()` можно сгруппировать по месяцам относительно длительности.

```
switch (m)
        {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7: 
        case 8: 
        case 10: 
        case 12: a = (1 <= date <= 31); break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11: a = (1 <= date <= 30); break;
        case 2: a = (); break;
        }
```

Ну или как вариант сделать массив с длительностями месяцев и обращаться к нему по индексу.
Вообще проверки можно сделать по очереди, начиная с года. Ведь если год неправильный, то дальше можно не проверять. Также если месяц введен некорректно, день месяца уже можно не проверять. И, повторюсь за Harry, - год проверять скорее всего не нужно. Ведь можно узнать правильность даты и в будущем, если хочется. Да и год может быть отрицательным - до нашей эры. Насчет года - уточните условие задачи.

```
const int MonthDuration[12]{ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
bool a = false;

if(year < 0)  // если год некорректный - выход из цикла с a == false
   break; 
if( month < 1 or month > 12)   // если месяц некорректный - выход из цикла с a == false
   break;
if( date < 1)   // если день некорректный - выход из цикла с a == false
   break;

if(m == 2)
   { } // обработка февраля
else
if( date <= MonthDuration[m-1] )
   a = true; // остальные месяцы
```

Также с массивом длительности месяцев будет проще подсчитать номер этого дня с начала года - второй вопрос в задании.

Comment: Пропущен 9-ый месяц. Мне кажется, не нужно заморачиваться с юлианским календарём, а конкретизировать условие задачи как "проверить корректность даты по григорианскому календарю", подразумевая, что он был всегда.